# jquery cycle plugin fade problems in firefox

Tags: jquery, cycle

I'm using the Cycle plugin for a slideshow. The images are supposed to crossfade into each other for the transitions. It is working properly in all browsers except firefox.

In firefox, the image doesn't fade out, but rather it flashes to black for a second while the new image fades on top of the black. I want them to fade into each other, which works in all the other browser.

The other transitions seem to be working properly. It's just this issue with the fade.

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening?

```
    $('#slider2').cycle({
      fx: 'fadeout',
      random: 1,
      timeout: 5000,    
      easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
      startingSlide: 2,
      speed: 1500,
});
```

Edit: Turns out this is a known bug in Firefox 10. There is a temporary solution if you read this thread. http://forums.asp.net/t/1767825.aspx/1?jQuery+cycle+plugin+functionality+broken+in+Firefox+10+0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this solution.

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/cycle-plugin-firefox-10-transparency-issues#14737000003067019

Comment: Thanks. So i guess it is a bug in Firefox 10. Adding a background color to the images did solve it though.

Comment: the "apply a background color to the images via the css" worked for me according to @pessi 's link.